# How to setup a Sencha ExtJS project currently built for desktop also work for mobile?

Tags: extjs, build-process

We have been developing using the default `classic` build descriptor so far to build dynamic web pages for desktop.

Now we need on the same application to work with mobile but not necessarily have the same home page on desktop or mobile load.

The user visits the page http://example.com using a desktop browser. Then he sees the view layout for the desktop
The user visits the page http://example.com using a mobile browser. Then he sees the view layout for the mobile (could be a total different view file)

We found this page inside documentation without much help: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/tablet_support.html

Actually a page that is currently working fully ok on desktop when switching to the Chrome Simulator (setting for example the Apple iPad simulator) we get the following errors in the console:

[image: console log]

We need the few steps that are necessary to setup it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a brand new application in ExtJS 6, you acess sencha cmd and call: "sencha generate app NameApp ../folderApp"

Then, the following structure is created: [Click here to see the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed9ef.jpg)

I don't know about the structure your code was created, but in order to work on desktop and mobile devices, it need to be in this structure generated by sencha cmd.

After to get this structure (generate a new application is a better practice for that) you need to put the "rigth model of extjjs 6.0" in your mind. ExtJS allow MVC or MVVM architetures. MVC architeture is basically controlled by a grand controller that can control all components of your application. In other hand, MVVM architeture have a controller for each view - it is instanciated when view is instanciated, and destroyed when view is destroyed. This architeture is recommended in ExtJS, especially in the lasts versions.

You have now to transfer the code done in your actual aplication to the new application and architeture. Put all your view structure in NameApp > classic > src > view. Open a new folder for each view. This folder should contain the view, and the controller for this view. For example, let's create a list view:

NameApp > classic > src > view > list > List.js

NameApp > classic > src > view > list > ListController.js

And so on...

Now you can create mobile views and controllers separated, on mobile > src > view folder, following the same model followed in classic, but you have to use components from mobile toolkit of course.

Until here, you have a separated mobile and classic app in the same code. But you can use the power of ExtJS 6 by extend generic classes from app folder, in order to optimize your code. For example, you can create a generic controller for an specific view, that will be extended in classic and modern folders:

NameApp > app > view > list > ListControllerGeneric.js

```
Ext.define('NameApp.app.view.list.ListControllerGeneric', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    //here you put code using in modern and classic both
});
```

NameApp > classic > src > view > list > ListController.js

```
Ext.define('NameApp.app.view.list.ListController', {
    extend: 'NameApp.app.view.list.ListControllerGeneric',
    //here you put code using in classic only
});
```

NameApp > modern > src > view > list > ListController.js

```
Ext.define('NameApp.app.view.list.ListController', {
    extend: 'NameApp.app.view.list.ListControllerGeneric',
    //here you put code using in modern only
});
```

One important thing to avoid crashes is to create all the views from the classic folder into the modern folder even if you do not actually use them on mobile. In addition when using both desktop and mobile you need sencha app watch modern to test both classic and modern but you need sencha app build to build both (or sencha app build  to build specific).

I hope this explanation can be useful for you. 
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your extensive response. We managed to find out what is happening. We just used the `modern` toolkit and we did **not** create one of our own as the `mobile` that you mentioned. One important thing to avoid crashes is to create all the views from the classic folder into the modern folder even if you do not actually use them on mobile. In addition when using both desktop and mobile you need `sencha app watch modern` to test both classic and modern **but** you need `sencha app build` to build both (or `sencha app build <toolkit>` to build specific). So if you can edit your answer..

Comment: Thanks George for your comments. I agree with you about create all views in both modern and classic. When I am developing universal applications, I run two instances of sencha cmd - sencha app watch modern and sencha app watch classic. Then when I change anything, the universal app is updated.  I don't understand where I have edit my answer. Help me to edit please.

Comment: I just meant edit your answer in order to include the things written in the comments in a more structured way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad, and I can't see what you have done and why it fails. The touch support named behind your link is for the classic toolkit, not for the modern, so if you want to use modern toolkit, forget about that link.

As with most of these framework changes, you are best off creating a new application environment (`sencha generate app`) and then porting (copying) your source code over. When generating a new application environment, don't provide a toolkit config, so a universal app is created.

Then don't just put all the code into a single directory. You have to dissect your existing code files into two parts: "Used for both toolkits" and "Used for classic only". Views are usually classic only, while some of the models and stores may be universal. The two parts go into two different directories: `src` for the universal part and `classic/src` for the classic part.

Only then write the views for modern toolkit (put them into `modern/src`), and everything should compile fine.

Comment: We are not creating a new application.
Instead we are trying to enhance the already existing application to work also in mobile with different layout. We believe that this can be done by enabling modern toolkit. We might be completely wrong... We are looking on how to setup correctly. Can you help?

Comment: @GeorgePligor You are completely wrong in both cases. You can't just "enable" the modern toolkit, you have to write the views from scratch, because they are not fully compatible (and I guess they will never be, although they will try hard for ExtJS7). And to setup such an universal app, the easiest way is to generate a "new" app and then put all your existing code into the appropriate directories, because the setup files (app.json, bootstrap.json etc) are not well documented.

Comment: I would like to point out that the best strategies for upgrades Sencha Touch -> ExtJS6 and ExtJS4 -> ExtJS6 are also to just generate a new app and copy over the JS code.

Comment: Just to clarify: We are already building using ExtJS6.
No need to migrate from ExtJS4 or ExtJS5

Comment: Please consider the expected behavior. Look above. We have edited the question. Thank you

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or shall we create a new question?

Comment: @GeorgePligor This is exactly what a ExtJS Universal App does. My answer still holds 100%. You should try to proceed as I told you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97636/discussion-between-george-pligor-and-alexander).

Comment: Alexander is right; the best way is to generate a new universal application and move your existing codebase in this new app.

Comment: @Ee-P The problem is that we don't have the right understanding on how ExtJS works. I will edit the question to make it more easy to answer. Alexander's answer has confused us further because he probably has the right model of extjs in his mind while we probably have the wrong one..

Answer (score 0):

Im very new to sencha, but i want to point out that using:

```
sencha app watch
```

tryied to find all my files on the app folder, even if i use "?modern" or use the chrome devs as a mobile user-agent.

Using:

```
sencha app watch modern
```

solved the issue. This command will check for the user-agent or the "?modern" and "?classic" tag and request the correct files.

This answer was originally in @Albanir Neves response, i just made it more clear here.